# c_00 not complete under p-norm

Tags: analysis

How do I prove that $c_{00}$ is complete under the p-norm, where $1 \leq p < \infty,$ I've done the cases where p = 1, p = 2 and p = infinity.

I'm really not sure here, of course $c_00$ is a subset of $l^1$ and x = (1,1/4,1/9,1/16,...,1/n^2,...) is in $l^1$ but not $c_{00}$; so I think this could be used as an appropriate example of a limit in this case; but I'm unsure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to verify whether $(C_{00},\|\cdot\|_p)$ is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388341/how-to-verify-whether-c-00-cdot-p-is-complete)